# Yoast canonical url and meta robots & Mage 1.7

Tags: extensions

Yoast canonical url and meta robots & Mage 1.7

Something I have been wondering about (and I think some others).

**Are the two YOAST plugins above still necessary in Mage 1.7?**

Comment: I can't remember exactly what that module does in entirety, but canonical support is now supported out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The canonical URL module is no longer required for canonical URLs because 1.7 (actually since 1.5 if I recall correctly) has two settings to enable them built into core now. You'll find these settings under the catalog section in System Configuration.

MetaRobot's functionality is, to my knowledge, not built into any version of Magento; but I could be wrong on this since I haven't poked around at the meta tags on search and login pages etc. So if you want those meta tags, then yes, you likely still need that module unless you want to implement them yourself to do something unique that the module doesn't do "just so"